# How to search an array, locate correct values, and change another 'value' in those rows only

Tags: php, arrays

How to search an array, locate if a value is equal to a string, and then take that row, find another value, and replace it. `$value['ID'] == 2;` I feel is the wrong way to go.

```
while($row = $result1 -> fetch_array())
{
    $columbs[] = $row;
}

$sort = array();

foreach($columbs as $key => $value) 
{
    $sort['schooltype'][$key] = $value['schooltype'];
    $sort['ID'][$key] = $value['ID'];

    foreach($columbs as $key=>$value)
    {
        if ($value['schooltype'] == "High School") 
        {
            $value['ID'] == 2;

            $sortbyschooltype = array("array" => $value['ID'], "SORT" => SORT_ASC);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a lot more writing explaining what I wanted to do but the error checker in stack overflow stopped me from describing more precisely what I mean so that's all I can say really.

Comment: Removed code snippet because it only used for `HTML/JavaScript/CSS` examples, also indented the code sample so it's looks more attractive.

Comment: `$value['ID'] == 2;` is wrong syntax. Shouldn't it be `$value['ID'] = 2;`?

Comment: @nempoBu4 Thanks matey. I couldn't get it to paste correctly in to SO.

Comment: @cyadvert I tried that first, it didn't work.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with the code. `$columbs[] = $row;` will create normal array. But this: `foreach($columbs as $key => $value)` is the way to work with associative arrays. In your case $key will be incrementing value from 0.... And I'm still not clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: Yes, the associative array is what I used to implement assigning keys and values to things. I wanted to do this, so that I may later try to search the array called '$columbs' for a row that contains a '$value['schooltype'] == "High School". If it returns a row, I want to change the '$value['ID']' from '1' to '2'. In other words, I'm trying to replace the contents, of a '$value['ID']'.  I tried array_splice but that was extensive and seemed like a waste of php resources.

Comment: still weird to me, but ok... If i understood you correctly, replacing `$value['ID'] == 2;` with `$value['ID'][$key] = 2;` should do the trick. No?

Comment: Yes! I have been doing this for days :) The answer was `$sort['ID'][$key]=0;` You made me think about why the `$value['ID']` and the `[$key]` would be combined. If you write the answer as so, I will mark you correct :)!

Answer (score 1):

`$sort['ID'][$key]=0;` Attribution to @cyadvert for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about [array_search](http://php.net/array-search)? No need to reinvent the wheel! This command will  return the index of the value you seek. Because your code is unclear to me, i can't give you a code example.